# Pass parameter from one form to another form within a view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two forms within a Show view.  I need to pass a variable to the 2nd form which is a post to Amazon payments api.

In the controller I have:

```
   def show
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @post }
     end
   end
```

In the view the first form shows the variable:

```
  <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <p>
  <b>referenceId:</b><br />
  <%= @post.referenceId %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

In this form I need to set the variable of referenceId using the above @post.referenceId.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
  <form action="https://authorize.payments-sandbox.amazon.com/pba/paypipeline"       method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="referenceId" value=@post.referenceId >
  <input type="image" src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/asp/golden_medium_paynow_withmsg_whitebg.gif" border="0">
  </form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand specifically what you want to do in your case, but in order to pass a variable to another form you can put it in a partial and then:

```
<%= render :partial => "second_form", :locals => { :my_var => my_value} %>
```

Comment: This makes some sense, so I put, <%= render :partial => 'posts/amazonpaybtn', :locals => { :referenceId => @post.id} %> Then in the partial, how do I use the referenceId I passed in the form? <input type="hidden" name="referenceId" value=<%= :referenceId %>>

Comment: Found it!   <input type="hidden" name="referenceId" value=<%= referenceId %> >  You nailed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can in the @post create method respond with JS and modify the hidden input value.

First modify the form helper to use remote

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:remote => true, :'data-type' => 'script'} do |f| %>
```

Then in the controller add

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js
  end
```

Then add a new view for create.js.erb

Add your javascript to modify the hidden referenceID in the view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not clear on this.  I'm not using a create action, just the Show action and view.